# Está negando acesso até com caracteres normais

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Esta linha de comando não esta deixando meu formulário acessar a database mesmo com todos os caracteres normais alguém que entende mais de `preg_match` pode me ajudar?

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$",$name)||!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$",$title)||!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$",$text)){ #verificando se o usuario está usando algum caractere invaido
            header("location: ../contato.php?contato=invalidcharacters");
            exit();
```

Comment: Qual é a string que não está a passar? não permites espaços em branco?

Comment: nao estava permitindo nada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sua expressão contem o caractere coringa `*`. O quantificador * corresponde ao elemento anterior ZERO ou mais vezes. Assim, mesmo que a seqüência de caracteres não contenha algum caractere não permitido, o matcher simplesmente dirá: zero combina.

O certo é usar `+` coincidência dos caracteres precedidos (NÃO PERMITIDOS) uma ou mais vezes.

Também ficou faltando `/` limites no final

Sua expressão corrigida:

`if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+$/",$name)||!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+$/",$title)||!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+$/",$text)){`

**Uma sugestão**

```
$string=$name.$title.$text;

if(!preg_match("/^[a-z]+?$/i", $string)){

 header("location: ../contato.php?contato=invalidcharacters");
 exit();

}
```

> Do início ( `^` ) ao fim ( `$` ) da string SÓ PODERÁ EXISTIR a quantidade que for ( `+?` ) de letras de a a z ( `[a-z]` ) maiusculas ou minusculas ( `i` ).
>
> ( `!` ) é a negativa da condição da expressão, ou seja, se a string não for constituída somente de letras maiúsculas ou minusculas.

Comment: nossa complicado esse método comecei a programar faz um mês e estou tendo muito dificuldade com estes métodos de segurança muito obrigado deu certo aqui.